# Laravel routing: Route in domain group visible also in local environment

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-9

What I need:
My app has a public domain
All routes in my Admin controller should be opened only if the remote domain is `domain1.com` and also in local environment.

**Currently:** if I put the admin panel route in the group, it is not visible in local environment any more, making it difficult to develop.

```
// My secret domain, accessible only for admins
Route::group(['domain'=>'domain1.com'],function(){

    Route::get('admin-panel', [App\Http\Controllers\Control\AdminController::class, 'admin_panel']);

});

// To be accessible both in domain1.com and domain2.com:
Route::get('homepage', [App\Http\Controllers\Control\PagesController::class, 'homepage']);
```

### Solutions

My current solution:
in route file `web.php` I add extra line

```
if( \App::environment() == 'local') {
    Route::get('admin-panel', [App\Http\Controllers\Control\AdminController::class, 'admin_panel']);
}
```

but it is a crude, temporary fix.

TODO:

- Either in route file or in the controller. A filter in a controller (for all or selected methods) would be best.
- An `if` clause checking if either the environment is local or the domain is `domain1.com`

Thank you.

Comment: you can also configure your vhost locally to server the domain domain1.com and change your host file and add `127.0.0.1 domain1.com` so you dont have to change anything in your code

Comment: That is a great solution too! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think laravel not support something like that. But you can declare the routes to a function variable and then use it in each domain.

```
$adminRoutes = function() {
    Route::get('admin-panel', [App\Http\Controllers\Control\AdminController::class, 'admin_panel']);
};

Route::group(array('domain' => 'domain1.com'), $adminRoutes);
Route::group(array('domain' => 'localhost'), $adminRoutes)
```